# How can I apply the same Pattern on two different Kafka Streams in Flink?

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I have this Flink program below:

```
object WindowedWordCount {
  val configFactory = ConfigFactory.load()

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)

    val kafkaStream1 = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010[String](topic1, new SimpleStringSchema(), props))
      .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new TimestampExtractor)

    val kafkaStream2 = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010[String](topic2, new SimpleStringSchema(), props))
      .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new TimestampExtractor)

    val partitionedStream1 = kafkaStream1.keyBy(jsonString => {
      extractUserId(jsonString)
    })

    val partitionedStream2 = kafkaStream2.keyBy(jsonString => {
      extractUserId(jsonString)
    })

    //Is there a way to match the userId from partitionedStream1 and partitionedStream2 in this same pattern?
    val patternForMatchingUserId = Pattern.begin[String]("start")
        .where(stream1.getUserId() == stream2.getUserId()) //I want to do something like this

    //Is there a way to pass in partitionedStream1 and partitionedStream2 to this CEP.pattern function?
    val patternStream = CEP.pattern(partitionedStream1, patternForMatchingUserId)

    env.execute()
  }
}
```

In the flink program above, I have two streams named `partitionedStream1` and `partitionedStream2` which is `keyedBy` the userID.

I want to somehow compare the data from both streams in the `patternForMatchingUserId` pattern (similar to how I showed above). Is there a way to pass in two streams to the `CEP.Pattern` function?

**Something like this:**

`val patternStream = CEP.pattern(partitionedStream1, partitionedStream2, patternForMatchingUserId)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can pass two streams to `CEP`, but you can pass a combined stream.

If both streams have the same type/schema. You can just union them. I believe this solutions matches your case.

```
partitionedStream1.union(partitionedStream2).keyBy(...)
```

If they have different schema. You can transform them into one stream using some custom logic inside e.g. [`coFlatMap`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/datastream_api.html#datastream-transformations).

Comment: So my partitionedStream1 is coming in from Kafka and every 3 seconds and my partitionedStream2 is coming in from Kafka every 8 seconds. For some reason when I do `val unionedStream = partitionedStream1.union(partitionedStream2)` then `unionedStream.print()` it is printing out the JSON data from partitionedStream1 twice and nothing from partitionedStream2. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: No it is not. Are you sure you've used right topic names for each partitionedStream?

Comment: Ahh that was the problem. I swear I checked against and I missed it twice. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have to know how I can do this in flink? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203168/how-to-attach-a-hashmap-to-a-configuration-object-in-flink